# Sailjs exposing controller from particular IP address

Tags: controller, sails.js

Is it possible to expose sailjs controller to request from particular IP address without authentication while requiring authentication for request from others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can do it.

Here's how

in your policy.js, add a specific policy on your route/controller method.

```
'*': ['isSpecificIP']
```

Now go in **api/policies** folder and create file called **isSpecificIP.js**

Add the following code in it -

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {

    if(req.ip == "::ffff:127.0.0.1" || req.ip == "127.0.0.1")
        next();

    else 
        return res.json(401, {err: 'Unauthorized'});
};
```

The above code allows only request from localhost to pass. The above code will also handle request from IPv6 address.

### **If it does not work**

If you have done this and still the server is not accepting your request, then

- print your IP address with 'Unauthorized' part like 
  `return res.json(401, {err: 'Unauthorized - ' + req.ip});`
- Ensure that you have restarted the server

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
You can create a policy for the route where request for all the ip addresses will be allowed. Inside that policy you can check the ip address using [req.ip](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/request-req/req-ip). After filtering you can use `res.redirect()` to route specific request to another url.